# If an Arduino goes to sleep, does the attached ESP also sleep?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am using Arduino Uno + an attached ESP-01 (ESP8266).

I want to save battery, so I made my Arduino get sleep & interrupt by a watchdog timer.

But if the Arduino goes to sleep, does the attached ESP also sleep?

Comment: you have to put the ESP8266 to sleep